# Difference between GROUP BY and DISTINCT, without aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, sql

What's the difference between DISTINCT and GROUP BY. I understand that DISTINCT removes replicated values and GROUP BY is often used with aggregate functions, but why is it that under the following code

```
    SELECT DISTINCT continent FROM world
    HAVING SUM(population) > 100000000;
```

only displays 1 continent and this:

```
    SELECT continent FROM world
    GROUP BY continent HAVING SUM(population) > 100000000;
```

Shows all each continent? 
I was doing question https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SUM_and_COUNT.
I'm trying to display each continent that has SUM(population) thats bigger than 100000000. Thanks guys.

Comment: Are you using MySQL?  In any case, you want to use the second version, which actually makes sense for your requirement.  MySQL overloaded the `HAVING` operator to do some fairly kinky things, one of which is that it can act like a `WHERE` clause, when used without `GROUP BY`.  But, use the second version.

Answer (score 1):

In MySql, one can't really trust the results of an aggregate function like SUM when you use DISTINCT.
Because with DISTINCT it's not actually grouping on the other columns.

Note that in other databases than MySql & relatives, that one wouldn't face such confusion.  Because those would complain about fields missing in the GROUP BY.

To explain it more visually.

With this sample data (MySql):

```
drop table if exists tmp_table;
create temporary table tmp_table (col1 int, col2 char(1), col3 int);

insert into tmp_table (col1, col2, col3) values
(1,'A',1),(2,'A',2),(3,'A',3),
(4,'B',4),(5,'B',5),(6,'B',6);
```

Via DISTINCT and SUM :

```
select distinct col2, sum(col3) from tmp_table;
```

Returns :

```
col2 sum(col3)
---- ---------
A           21
```

Via GROUP BY :

```
select col2, sum(col3) from tmp_table group by col2;
```

Returns :

```
col2 sum(col3)
---- ---------
A            6
B           15
```

Then when we include the HAVING clause to those queries

```
... having sum(col3) > 10;
```

Then the first select will return the wrong result: `('A',21)`
And the second select will return what you'd expect : `('B',15)`

Comment: `select distinct col2, sum(col3) from tmp_table;` will only return an error. It's invalid standard SQL and will be rejected by any self-respecting DBMS.

Comment: You are right.  I forgot  that the question had the mysql tag missing.  Since that sqlzoo website defaults to mysql, and this is your typical MySql issue, I just assumed that this was about MySql. Anyway, corrected.